# How to load Google map link from Ajax request to a div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load the google map in div by a ajax request therefore, I've tried below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.lnk').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(url);
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Web page test.html</h1>
<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=6.9906664862927625,+80.74805527925491&aq=&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=36.094886,86.572266&vpsrc=0&ie=UTF8&t=m&z=14&ll=6.990666,80.748055&output=embed" title="Get extern" class="lnk">Get extern</a>
<div id="content">load here</div>
```

This code does not load the map but instead google map url if I tried a external html file to load then it works. Could any please tell how load a google map in ajax request to a div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser is not gonna let you load anything from a different server in a div because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

What you could do is loading the map in an `iframe`, that is a section of your HTML where you can load external sites securely.

This would be the HTML:

```
<h1>Web page test.html</h1>
<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=6.9906664862927625,+80.74805527925491&aq=&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=36.094886,86.572266&vpsrc=0&ie=UTF8&t=m&z=14&ll=6.990666,80.748055&output=embed" title="Get extern" class="lnk">Get extern</a>
<iframe id="content">load here</iframe>​
```

And this the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.lnk').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').attr('src', url);
        return false;
    });
});​
```

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GZBbk/)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. This very helpful to me and actually you saved me. But just another question can't we have alternate tag for the iframe or object to use your above script ?

Comment: A different html element <div> or <span> ? Becuase Iframe and Object elements are really new our site.

Comment: Nope, iframe's purpose is loading external content into your website, which is actually what you are looking for. Anyway, you can modify the 'iframe' as you would with a `div` or `span`, you can modify it's width, height, etc., using `CSS`

Comment: Actually I tried loading into a div but it's not working. See example http://jsfiddle.net/GZBbk/4/

Comment: Please, read again my answer again. You can't load external content into a `div`, it should be done in an `iframe`